# Prevent JTree from expanding after drag and drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jtree, expand

After I drag and drop a node, the new parent of the node expands. I want to disable this.

I extended the class `TransferHandler` and overrode the method `importData`.
In this method I do the actual move. After the move of the node I check if the parent node `isExpanded` and I get `false` as an answer.
So where or how can I cancel the expansion?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [addTreeWillExpandListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#addTreeWillExpandListener(javax.swing.event.TreeWillExpandListener)) and add a listener like this:

```
public class DisableExpansionListener implements TreeWillExpandListener {
    @Override
    public void treeWillExpand(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException {
        throw new ExpandVetoException(event, "Disallow all expansions!");
    }

    @Override
    public void treeWillCollapse(TreeExpansionEvent event) throws ExpandVetoException
        // allow collapsing!
    }
}
```

Comment: As I understand it will disable the possibility to expand the tree. I only want to disable the automatic expansion after the drag and drop. Thanks.

Comment: I know, but you already implemented a TransferHandler, so it should be possible to add the listener when the drag is started and remove it again once it's finished.

Comment: Ok. I see what you did there ;) I wish there were a better solution though